# Separate Strings with "-" inbetween them

Tags: php, string

I have a string of "2011-03-06" how do I separate it so it can be $day "06" $month "03" $year "2011"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to separate the elements, and [`list()`](http://php.net/list) to assign them to three separate variables.

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are really two ways to do this.  The first is with string manipulation, as shown by the other answers.

A **better** way of doing it would be to use PHP's date processing code:

```
$date = "2011-03-06";

$time = strtotime($date);
// or
$time_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Then you can display `$time` however you want using the [`date`](http://php.net/date) command with `$time` as the second argument or `DateTime`'s [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) command.